# Length and spacing autocorrelation with FFT

Tags: fft, fourier-transform, autocorrelation

I have calculated, with FFT and A-FFT, the autocorrelation of a discrete signal (coming from an integration) with spacing $\Delta T$ composed by $N$ samples padded to $2N$ with zeroes.

What is the resolution of the autocorrelation? Is it $\frac{\Delta T}{2}$?

What is the time interval of validity of the calculated autocorrelation? $[0, N]$ or $[0, \frac{N}{2}]$?

Comment: Would [dsp.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: i presume you first zero-padded, did a $2N$-point FFT, computed magnitude-square of each FFT bin (zeroing the imaginary part), $2N$-point inverse FFT and the result should be $$ R_x[k] = \sum\limits_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} x[n] x[n+k] $$ where $x[n]$ is $N$ non-zero samples padded to infinity with zeros.  i might guess that the time interval of the discrete autocorrelation is $2N$ and would be symmetrical about $k=0$ or $k=\frac{2N}{2}=N$.

Comment: Yes! Ok! And is the resolution of autocorrelation R Dt/2 ?

Comment: without further interpolation of $R_x[k]$, the resolution of the autocorrelation is 1 sample.  just like the resolution of $x[n]$ is without interpolation.  samples for either sequence represent the same amount of time.